# Asset Pipeline :: Specific Resource compilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

How can I run specific compilation tasks with rails/asset pipeline/sprockets within my application?

Basically, I have sets of user created css for an application; users upload css for their parts of the application (security considerations aside etc, already handled). How do I run a task to compile specific css sets into the main css I have? This is not a live compilation issue, I just want to take an input, compile that to a file, and serve that that on demand, which is more a 'I need this set of css precompiled at will when I want to precompile it within a running application'

I'm updating something implemented previously where I was able to haphazardly serve user generated css, I'd like to integrate this with the asset pipeline. How can I get greater control over the asset pipeline? I'm assuming I need to learn more about Sprockets, but I'd be curious what anyone could add to assist.

Comment: Possibly create a manifest that I can pass a variable (the specific css) to, then run that to output a unique bundle of css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per user CSS files would be possible, but to use Sprockets and the pipeline in the intended way to generate the files is going to take a bit of messing about.

To generate a user CSS file you are going to have to:

**1. Generate a manifest for the user.**

The manifest would include the main css via a sprockets directive, and require self at the end along with the user css.

The manifest file would need a name that is unique to the user

**2. Compile the manifest.**

You won't want to compile them all, so you'll need to write something to do just the one you want.

**3. Add the new manifest to the pipeline manifest**

This is a YAML file that holds the mappings between the name of manifests and files in the pipeline and their hashed counter-parts. You'll need to add your new (or updated) file hash to this without clobbering the other entries.

**4. Restart your app.**

This is required because Rails read in the pipeline manifest when it starts up, so you would not see any changes you'd made until this occurs.

==

Then you will be able to reference the username based CSS file for the user.

The with this approach is that each time you deploy the custom manifest would  be overwritten.

If you are storing the user's custom CSS in the database you could write out the custom user manifests at each deploy.

Another approach is to use the pipeline for the main CSS and ignore it completely for the user CSS, just doing what you do now. Use on link for the pipeline CSS and a second for the user CSS. You could still minify the CSS when the file is created, but if the extra request is out of the question then something based on the above.

Best of luck!

Comment: The second is easier to process, queue, and output to a minified file right now.